# Why won't Windows 7 rejoin domain?

Tags: windows-7, networking, domain

With Windows 7, I was working with a domain, we'll call it `DOMAIN-A`, for months without any problem. Then, recently I joined another domain, `DOMAIN-B`, for a couple of days.

I've left `DOMAIN-B` and wish to rejoin `DOMAIN-A` again, however it won't allow me. I'm getting an error saying;

> DOMAIN-A could not be contacted.

My DNS settings are all fine. Has anyone seen this problem before? I've flushed the DNS entries and tried some other solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: How are you trying to switch domains? Can you give us a little more detail into what you've tried? As it stands, your question is rather vague which makes it difficult to answer in a way most helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft says this message can indicate issues with your domain controller, and implies it could also mean issues with your network.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms839183.aspx:

> Explanation:
>
> Your domain controller may be malfunctioning. When you log on to a
>   domain, the logon information is saved, but changes to your profile
>   may not be. If a workstation tries to join the network with a computer
>   name that is the same as a Windows 2000 domain name, the Windows 2000
>   Workstation service on all workstations participating in the domain
>   fails to start during system startup. Workstations already logged on
>   before the duplication of the domain name will continue to operate
>   successfully. User Action:
>
> You can still log on, but you may want to wait until the domain
>   controller can be contacted. When this error is reported by
>   workstations in a domain, identify the computer, remove it from the
>   network, and configure it with a unique computer name. To identify the
>   computer, use STAT32, WINMSD, or another utility to resolve the name
>   in question to an Ethernet address. The Ethernet address can then be
>   used to trace the workstation.

Can you ping your domain controller for Domain A?

Can you access other network resources on Domain A, such as the internet, other servers and workstations, etc?

Try pinging the domain controller by name "serverA" and by ip address. If the name resolves to a different IP, you have a DNS issue on your network. If the name doesn't resolve at all you have a DNS issue on your network, or a network issue on your network. :)

A firewall could also block this. When you look at your network settings, is the network for Domain A listed as a "Work" network or "Public" network? It should be a "Work" network to allow the firewall to communicate properly.

Comment: Hi..thanks for your help..
yes I can ping the domain controllers IP address and can ping it by the machine name..I can also ping the server name..
I can access network drives on Domain A..
It is a work network and Ive disabled my firewalls..still no luck :(